# Can I condition on a variable being of type String?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to do this in java?

If variable is a `String` do one operation, otherwise perform another operation.

For example, given variable `a`

```
if a is a string
    close program
else
    continue program
```

I'm looking for the code that checks to see if the variable is a `String` or not.

Comment: what is a string?  you have declared it as String in Java?

Comment: Please give a code example of what you have tried so we can see what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instanceof` operator is what you use in Java when you want to test whether the given object is of a certain type.

```
if(x instanceof String) {
  String s = (String) x;
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

The use of such type-checks is discouraged in OOP. You should rather try to solve your problem by employing subtype polymorphism (or inheritance, if you will). (If you describe your specific problem, we could assist you with it.)

---

An interesting factoid: Scala, another statically typed language on JVM, has a following construct that lets you match over type and cast to that type in one clause:

```
x match {
  case s: String => ...
  case _ => ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (x instanceof String) {
   // do one thing
} else { 
   // do something else
}
```

Or like this:

```
if ((x != null) && String.class.equals(x.getClass())) {
   // do one thing
} else { 
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: The first form is better as it won't throw a NullPointer on x.getClass()

Comment: @Steve why would the 2nd form throw a NullPointer? x.getClass() will only be invoked if x is not null.

Comment: @emory That is because duffymo edited his post after Steve's comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (myvariable instanceof String) {
     // Yes! It's a string
}
```

Comment: @Randy A regex question? I don't see any mention of regex anywhere.

Comment: it is not mentioned... but the question is vague, and i think the OP might be looking for a 'string' not say a 'number' - just a guess...

Answer (score 1):

```
if(x instanceof String) 
{
    //Close
}
else
{
   //Continue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way is, to use instanceof. But method overloading can be used as well:

```
public class IsString
{
    public IsString ()
    {
      System.out.println ("String: " + isString ("7"));
      Object o = "object";
      System.out.println ("Object: " + isString (o));
      System.out.println ("o instanceof String ?= " + (o instanceof String));
    }

    public boolean isString (String p)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean isString (Object o)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new IsString ();
    }
}
```

But there is a difference: If the reference is declared as Object, the String isn't detected, while instanceof will detect it.

Comment: I wrote essentially the same answer, but was informed that it doesn't work if a `String` instance is stored in a variable of `Object` type, for example. However, I cannot confirm this personally at the moment.

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer, to underline the difference.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`JavaDoc`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html),

> The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified type. You
>   can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance
>   of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular
>   interface.

Use the instanceOf like this,

```
if (variable instanceof String) {
     //  It's a string
}
```